# How do i make sure a variable is not being part of an HQL Query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a strange problem. I want a particular variable to be set to null(should not be part of the HQL query). How can i achieve this.

My File

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHECK_PRODUCTS")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CHECK_NO")
public class VwCheckProducts extends VwCheckProductsMaterials implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1593919250034321815L;


    @Column(name="CHECK_NO",length=18)
    private Long bookingNo;     


    @Column(name="CHECK_TYPE",length=12)
    private String checkType;       

    @Column(name="CHECK_REASON",length=24)
    private String checkReason;     

    //setters and getters
    }
```

Now when i do

```
checkList.addAll(q.list());
```

Below is the hibernate query getting formed

```
select checkProductsc0_.CHECK_NO as CHECK_N_1_311_, checkProductsc0_1_.CHECK_TYPE as CHECK_TY2_311_, vcheckProducts0_1_.CHECK_REASON as CHECK_REA3_311_ 
from CHECK_PRODUCTS vwcheckProductsc0_
```

Now what i want is i want the `CHECK_REASON` to be skipped from the HQL query and the HQL query to be formed as

```
select checkProductsc0_.CHECK_NO as CHECK_N_1_311_, checkProductsc0_1_.CHECK_TYPE as CHECK_TY2_311_ as CHECK_REA3_311_ 
    from CHECK_PRODUCTS vwcheckProductsc0_
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Do you want this to happen for specific queries or all?

Comment: Yes priyesh exactly. This should happen only for one specific user.

Comment: Then you can write a custom HQL query and not use the generated one.

Comment: Can you share the query string you are using?

Comment: If in case i want to make it for all then. how do i work with the generated one?

Comment: I have updated the query that was formed

Comment: Do you mean, you want to make the same query behave differently for different users? I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know how you created the object 'q'.

Comment: query.append(" VwCheckProducts  vw ");

Comment: Try 'select bookingNo, checkType from VwCheckProducts vw' where you create the query string.